I read the postmeta and update it without changing it, then move on to the next record
I made a survey application.
The survey works successfully when I email it to 4,000 users.
However, when I send it via SMS, there is an error in the numbers.
The reason is that when I send an e-mail, not all users enter data at the same time.
However, when I send it via SMS, there are many entries at the same time, I have to read the postmeta, update it without changing it, and then move on to the next record.
What do you suggest, some of the code is below.
Thank you very much to everyone who is interested.
Option A;
function uD_Option_A_Increase(){
//Read
$uD_Option_A= get_post_meta( $uD_post_ID, 'uD_Option_A_Value' );
//Increase
$uD_Option_A_Plus= $uD_Option_A + 1;
//Update
update_post_meta( $uD_post_ID, 'uD_Option_A_Value', $uD_Option_A_Plus );
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

2 things: 1) "I have to … update [the postmeta] without changing it" — Updating the post meta value does change it. I'm not sure what you're saying here. 2) get_post_meta( $uD_post_ID, 'uD_Option_A_Value' ); will return an array (see the get_post_meta() docs). Incrementing an array by 1 won't work. (If you want a single value, you should use get_post_meta( $uD_post_ID, 'uD_Option_A_Value' , true ); and even then you should ensure it returns a numeric value (is_numeric() will help).
